# UnitTest ExpectedException with multiple Exceptions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I want one TestMethod for multiple exceptions. The Problem ist that the Testmethod stops after the first thrown exception.

I know that I can do something like that:

```
try 
{
  sAbc.ToInteger();
  Assert.Fail(); // If it gets to this line, no exception was thrown
} 
catch (ArgumentException) { }
```

But I want to use the following code-base:

```
[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), "...")]
public void StringToIntException()
{
    sAbc.ToInteger(); // throws an exception and stops here
    sDecimal.ToInteger(); // throws theoretically a exception too...
}
```

And I don't want to create one testmethod for each possible exception like that:

```
[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), "...")]
public void StringToIntException()
{
    sAbc.ToInteger();
}

[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), "...")]
public void StringToIntException()
{
    sDecimal.ToInteger();
}
```

**Edit from 2018-11-09:**

Today this will work based on Jan David Narkiewicz suggestion. But as I already mentioned. From my standpoint today this would be a bad design for a test. Example:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ExceptionTest()
    {
        Assert.ThrowsException <FormatException> (() =>
        {
            int.Parse("abc");
        });

        Assert.AreEqual(0.1m, decimal.Parse("0.1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        Assert.ThrowsException<FormatException>(() =>
        {
            decimal.Parse("0.1", new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been 7 years since the question was asked, so Assert.ThrowsException is available in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting for Visual Studio 2017.

```
Assert.ThrowsException<exception type goes here>(() =>
{
    code that throw exception here
});
```

Assert.ThrowsException does not look like it existed in Visual Studio 2015. Exercise left to the reader to verify.

Comment: Yes you are right. My needs from lots of years ago are satisfied... :-). But from my today viewpoint I'm not sure if this would be correct test... :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is impossible with Attributes because when you exception is thrown, the execution of the methods is interrupted. Therefore if you have an exception at the first line, the second won't be executed.

If you really need the feature, use nUnit which has:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(delegate { /*Your code*/ });
```

Comment: how about or-type multiple exceptions? only one exception will happen at a time. Is this achievable by mstest?